# Style Option Element Safari Mac

Tags: macos, colors, safari, html-select

After extensive testing, I believe it is not possible to change the color of the text in an option element of a select dropdown in Safari for Mac. (By that I mean have the text of some option elements one color, and others a different color). I've tried css, inline styles, JS, and (shock) a font tag.

It does work in Safari for PC however! Also chrome, IE and firefox on both platforms. It does work in safari mac if you use a "multiple" select, but not single line/traditional select box.

Can someone confirm?

(BTW, I don't really want to be told "you shouldn't do this" or "why ever would you want to do that", etc, just confirmation that it either is impossible, or an explanation of some way of doing it).

Thanks!

Comment: Here are someone's findings by trial and errors as far as I can tell: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/style-optgroup-option-css-safari/ The article is from 2009, so not sure how accurate it still is for newer versions...